# Taylor series for tetration

Tags: taylor-expansion, tetration

I would like to know what is known about Taylor series for tetration (and other hyper-exponentiations).

Surprisingly, such information is rare on internet. Numerical values for expansion in hyperexponent for tetration with basis $e$ can be found here:

http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Tetration#Taylor_expansion_at_zero

However I am interested in expansion in the *basis* of tetration. I look for

$$ x \uparrow \uparrow m = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(m)x^n $$

Wolfram mathematica gives me wired result (obviously a bug) at $x=0$ for $x \uparrow 3$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+x%5E(x%5Ex)

where in the output $log(x)$ appears (not a polynomial).

It is better at $x=1$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+x%5E(x%5Ex)+at+x%3D1

I imagine the point $x=0$ may be "peculiar", but at least expansion at $x=1$ should be possible.

List of my questions:

1) Is tetration analytic at $x=0$? At $x=1$?

2) If yes, is an explicit closed-form formula for $c_n(m)$ known? (at any of these points)

3) If not, is an explicit closed-form formula for $c_n(m)$ know for some specific values of $m$?

4) Same questions for extension to higher hyper-exponentiations...

Thank you.

Comment: I little advice, don't loose too much time on these themes : either on the point of view of practical applications or on the theoretical side, hyper-exponentiations of different kinds are a little a deadend.

Comment: I know it's a long time now, but I happened to be looking up the very same question. I couldn't help being amused by your little _admonishon_ - yes it is a very frustrating subject all this _hyperoperations_ business; and one gets the distinct impression that the series of mathematical operations defined recursively as the previous one applied to n instances of the variable _does not_ (except for natural numbers alone) extend beyond the third - _exponentiation_. However, I do think this little 'island' of tractibility is truly a gem; and I would say to OP "have this amongst your crown jewels"!

Comment: There should be a method for solving finding coefficients at $x=1$ of height $m$ and at $x=0$ for $e^x\uparrow\uparrow m$ as multiple finite sums like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314712/calculating-the-nth-super-root-when-n-is-greater-than-2/4697772#4697772).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x \uparrow \uparrow m$ is never analytic at $x = 0$ for $m > 1$. For example, consider $m = 2$, then you have the function $x \uparrow \uparrow 2 = x^x = e^{x \ln x}$ which clearly has a branch point at $x = 0$ and hence is not analytic. You can see this if we substitute $\ln x = 2\pi i n + \log x$ where $\log$ represents the principal branch of the logarithm, in which case we have $x^x = e^{x (2\pi i n + \log x)} = e^{x 2 \pi i n} e^{x\log x}$, which certainly depends on $n$ as long as $x$ is not an integer. You have similar problems for all $m > 1$.

The function $x \uparrow \uparrow m$ is always analytic at $1$, which can be seen inductively: Clearly for $m=1$ it is analytic at $1$. If $x \uparrow \uparrow m$ is analytic at 1, then $x \uparrow \uparrow{(m+1)} = e^{(\ln x)(x\uparrow \uparrow m)}$ is analytic at $1$ because $\exp$ is analytic everwhere and $\ln$ is analytic at 1. The Taylor series of $x \uparrow \uparrow m$ at $1$ is not very nice, but the terms can be computed explicitly. [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) tells us that $$ (e^x) \uparrow\uparrow m = \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{(n+1)^n}{(n+1)!} x^n + \sum_{n = m+1}^\infty a_{m n} x^n$$ where $a_{m n}$ have a rather complicated recursive formula. To compute the Taylor series of $x \uparrow\uparrow m$ at $1$, you could compose the above series with the series for $\ln(x)$ at $1$ using [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version). Not very simple, but it probably as close to a closed form as you will get.

Comment: Surprisingly, discussing the *tetration of the pascalmatrix $P$*, I arrived at the same powerseries solution for the tetration as your's here. If interested, see http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/PascalMatrixTetrated.pdf at my webspace.

Comment: Interesting (and probably a computationally friendlier method) but it shouldn't be surprising. Power series are unique, so whatever other tetration techniques you have they must agree with this for integer heights.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the tetration of the function $e^x$
$$^n(e^x)=(e^x)_1^{(e^x)_2^{(e^x)_3^{_..^{.e^x_n}}}}$$

For a natural number n, the taylor series of that function is

$$^n(e^x)=\sum_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}*T(n,k)*x^k$$

where $T(n,k)$ is the [OEIS A210725](https://oeis.org/A210725) (if k<n, $T(n,k)=T(k,k)$)

then, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$^n(x)=\sum_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}*T(n,k)*(ln(x))^k$$

On the limit for $n\to\infty$, the T(n,k)=T(k,k) are the coefficients of the [Lambert w function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

There are other series, that you can find [here](https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/attachment.php?aid=189).

For code able to calculate tetrations with high precision, (for a limited set of bases, and $n\in\mathbb{R}$) check [Sheldonison's fatou.gp code](https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1017)

In Wolframalpha, you can get the series of $^n(x+1)$, and it will produce the Stirling transform of $^n(e^x)$. The series has power of x, and no logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

I think really the extension of the *progression* of operations by introducing a new one that is the $n$-fold iteration of the thus-far highest one is a process that on the face of it kindof *looks like* it ought to be susceptible of being plied indefinitely ... but at the end of the day *isn't*! (Except in *this* case to the natural numbers *only*.) You get it with complex-quaternion-octonion-etc also - *that* progression seems also to *fizzle-out* rather disappointingly; and a similar principle seems to be *abroad* in very many areas of mathematics. Sometimes I *so want* this or that progression to be extensible without limit ... but then I find eventually that I need to resign myself to the first two or three items of the progression being beautiful special cases. I must admit, though ... sometimes it's actually quite a *relief*!

However - I *do* think that business of relating the tetration by $n$ of the *exponential* function to the *Lambert w* function as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and the way there is a taylor series for the function at *finite* $n$ with coefficients that can be found by a recursion algorithm - *and* the way they 'peel-away' term-by-term to leave the coefficients of the *lambert w* function: I do find that to be an extraordinarily *sweet* little oasis in the midst of a parched desert ... and it is certainly an item that I treasure amongst my *crown jewels*!

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Expanding as Taylor series aound $x=1$ as
$$f_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k\,(x-1)^k$$ see how fast converge the coefficients
$$f_1=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{12},\frac{3}{40},-\frac{1}{120},\frac{59}
   {2520},-\frac{71}{5040},\frac{131}{10080}\right\}$$
$$f_2=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2},\frac{53}{40},\frac{233}{180},\frac{56
   27}{5040},\frac{2501}{2520},\frac{8399}{10080}\right\}$$
$$f_3=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},3,\frac{163}{40},\frac{1861}{360},\frac{33641}{504
   0},\frac{8363}{1008},\frac{22391}{2160}\right\}$$
$$f_4=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},4,\frac{243}{40},\frac{3421}{360},\frac{71861}{504
   0},\frac{54371}{2520},\frac{69281}{2160}\right\}$$
$$f_5=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},4,\frac{283}{40},\frac{4321}{360},\frac{102941}{50
   40},\frac{85871}{2520},\frac{61333}{1080}\right\}$$
$$f_6=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},4,\frac{283}{40},\frac{4681}{360},\frac{118061}{50
   40},\frac{106661}{2520},\frac{81583}{1080}\right\}$$
$$f_7=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},4,\frac{283}{40},\frac{4681}{360},\frac{123101}{50
   40},\frac{115481}{2520},\frac{93013}{1080}\right\}$$
$$f_8=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},4,\frac{283}{40},\frac{4681}{360},\frac{123101}{50
   40},\frac{118001}{2520},\frac{97333}{1080}\right\}$$
$$f_9=\left\{1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{3},4,\frac{283}{40},\frac{4681}{360},\frac{123101}{50
   40},\frac{118001}{2520},\frac{97333}{1080}\right\}$$

Comment: Are these continued fractions?

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar. No, they are the coefficients $c_k$